# RUM browser SDK sample rate

Tags: datadog

I had a quick question regarding the `sampleRate` property in the RUM browser SDK initialization parameters. I can see from the [documentation](https://github.com/DataDog/browser-sdk/blob/main/packages/rum/README.md#initialization-parameters) that the type is `number`, but I'm having a hard time determining if it supports floating point values. I currently have a sample rate of 1% set up, and I wanted to know if it would be possible to drop it to 0.5%.

```
datadogRum.init({
  applicationId: "",
  clientToken: "",
  site: "datadoghq.com",
  service: "",
  sampleRate: 1,
  trackInteractions: true,
})
```

Does the SDK support using `0.5` for a 0.5% sampling rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running a quick test, I was able to confirm that the Datadog RUM browser SDK accepts a floating-point value for the sample rate. So setting a value of `0.5` will successfully set the rate to 0.5%.

Comment: Yay, thanks for sharing! Feel free to Accept your own answer as correct!